# how to allow % in regex expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

i have following function where i also want to allow **%**

for now it is allowing :

```
//4 special character are allowed.
    //' (single quote)
    //- (hyphen)
    //. (dot)
    //  (single space)
```

**i want to allow 5th charterer there as : %**

```
var RegExPattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9 '.-/%]+$/;
        var str = averageGPACount;
        if (self.averageGPA() != "") {
            if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(str) == false) {
                validationPass = false;
            }
            else {
                $('#txtaverageGPA').removeClass("errorHighlight");
                validationPass = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would always make the `-` the last character in the sequence, otherwise it may be treated as a range like in `A-Z`!

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```
var RegExPattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9 '.%-]+$/;
```

- hyphen needs to be at 1st or last position to avoid escaping.
- `%` doesn't need to be escaped inside a character class.